# JavaScript with shortcode inside of URL redirect?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, redirect, shortcode

I've got a JavaScript redirect with php calling for a shortcode inside my page template on wordpress.

```
<script language="javascript">
(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
var __redirect_to = 'http://dsdomination.com/sp/pro?aid=<?php echo do_shortcode("[affiliateself type='DSDomination' default='ClintonLee83']"); ?>';//

var _tags = ['button', 'input', 'a'], _els, _i, _i2;
for(_i in _tags) {
    _els = document.getElementsByTagName(_tags[_i]);
    for(_i2 in _els) {
        if((_tags[_i] == 'input' && _els[_i2].type != 'button' && _els[_i2].type != 'submit' && _els[_i2].type != 'image') || _els[_i2].target == '_blank') continue;
        _els[_i2].onclick = function() {window.onbeforeunload = function(){};}
    }
}

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {};
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.location.href = __redirect_to;
        }, 500);
    },5);
    return 'Are you sure?';
}
}, 500);
})();
</script>
```

I believe the ' and " are conflicting with eachother. the javascript won't work when I add the php calling for the shortcode. How can I implement this?

Comment: what is the output of `do_shortcode(etc..)` ?

Comment: If this is in a `php` file (page template) then it should work, `do_shortcode` should return a value.

Comment: What do you mean "won't work"?  Do you see errors in your console?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't set `document.location.href` inside the `onbeforeunload`.  I'm not sure if browsers will let you do that, they may block it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, it seems [working](http://jsfiddle.net/rQK9A/), is this possible using `setTimeout` ?

Comment: @RCV: Maybe it does work.  Wasn't sure.  Either way, I'm sure users will love it! :)

Comment: For some reason, the exit popup will not appear and there will be no redirect when I add the <?php echo do_shortcode("[affiliateself type='DSDomination' default='ClintonLee83']"); ?> (crtl+k not working in the comments :D) so it acts like a normal page would when leaving.